# How can I improve data saving in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I've finally managed to get the Apple Food Tracker tutorial app working, albeit by using a completely different approach to the rating control. For those not familiar with the app, it allows you to create and edit a simple array of "meal" records.

In order to speed the app up, I'm only saving the data to file when the app closes rather than every time an item is added, edited or deleted.

The problem is that the save seems quite slow, even with just three of four items. If I reopen the app too soon after closing, the data reverts to the previous save.

Here is my save function, in the table view controller that holds the data model:

```
public func saveMeals() {
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(meals, toFile: Meal.ArchiveURL.path)
    if !isSuccessfulSave {
        print("Failed to save meals")
    }
}
```

And here is the call from AppDelegate:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

    if let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
        if let viewController = rootViewController.viewControllers.first as? MealTableViewController {
            viewController.saveMeals()
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a better, faster way of saving, or can I prevent the app from closing before the save is complete? Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit: It appears that sometimes the save function doesn't get called. How can that be if I always close the app with the table view controller visible?

Comment: C o r e  D a t a

Comment: Do not shy away from Core Data. It is an excellent framework.

Comment: Thanks Leo, I've signed up for an online course which covers core data among many other things. Just out of interest, I've got the Food Tracker app to work better by moving the save function to applicationDidEnterBackground.